# Refresh Form page after submitting the form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I use `target="_blank"` for my form submission to open the resulting page in new window but the previous or form page is still open and holding the values filled for form submission . If i click submit again it submits again with same values, so how would i refresh form page after submission.

```
<form target="_blank" id="monthly_form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'billing/monthly_slip'; ?>">
..form fields
...
</form>
```

Comment: Here ajax seems the best approach

Comment: write reset() js function and call when you click on submitt button

Comment: ajax is da way... or you have to write form and manage data on the same page

Comment: Ajax is entirely useless in this situation. It is used when you want to make an HTTP request without disturbing the page or opening a new window … and both of those things are desired!

Comment: Yes I agree with Royal, AJAX seems tobe the best for this situation

Comment: @RoyalBg i thought it would much easier to use target="_blank" is much simpler and is there an event that i can use after form submission

Comment: This way you would need two events - a javascript reload and a target="_blank" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.location.reload()
```

should work

Answer (score 2):

try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#your_form_id').on('submit', function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          setTimeout(function() {
               window.location.reload();
          },0);
          this.submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="window.location.reload()">
<input type="submit" value='go' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `target="_blank"` for form submission, Instead post the form normally and redirect from controller. But if you really need to use `target="_blank"` then after form submit just reload the page or reset the form.